# Flutter app fails to log in using google Sign In

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Edit :- Interestingly my practice app with exact same code shows same console logs but work absolutely fine but the main app (this app) doesnt work.

My app was working fine till a few hours ago but since morning login fails with this error

```
E/flutter (24958): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
```

Stackoverflow says to change com.android.tools.build:gradle. How did this suddenly happen I dint even touch the code.

Console:

```
W/ActivityThread( 1327): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@1796f22
V/ViewRootImpl( 1327): The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
D/DecorView( 1327): onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@d773c2a[SignInHubActivity]
D/DecorView( 1327): onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@e79156a[MainActivity]
E/flutter ( 1327): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
E/flutter ( 1327): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:572:7)
E/flutter ( 1327): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:161:18)
E/flutter ( 1327): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1327): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
E/flutter ( 1327): #3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:361:48)
E/flutter ( 1327): #4      MethodChannelGoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/src/method_channel_google_sign_in.dart:45:10)
E/flutter ( 1327): #5      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:233:42)
E/flutter ( 1327): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1327): #6      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:288:18)
E/flutter ( 1327): #7      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:359:9)
E/flutter ( 1327): #8      signInWithGoogle (package:opinion/services/google_sign_in.dart:8:71)
E/flutter ( 1327): #9      LoginButton.build.<anonymous closure> (package:opinion/components/login_button.dart:45:21)
E/flutter ( 1327): #10     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
E/flutter ( 1327): #11     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter ( 1327): #12     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter ( 1327): #13     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter ( 1327): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter ( 1327): #15     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:219:7)
E/flutter ( 1327): #16     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:477:9)
E/flutter ( 1327): #17     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:78:12)
E/flutter ( 1327): #18     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:124:9)
E/flutter ( 1327): #19     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter ( 1327): #20     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:18)
E/flutter ( 1327): #21     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:108:7)
E/flutter ( 1327): #22     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:220:19)
E/flutter ( 1327): #23     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter ( 1327): #24     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter ( 1327): #25     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter ( 1327): #26     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter ( 1327): #27     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter ( 1327): #28     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 1327): #29     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter ( 1327): #30     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter ( 1327): #31     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter ( 1327): 
I/flutter ( 1327): null
```

Comment: did you add SHA1 fingerprints to firebase

Comment: @gladiator Hi. yes as I said everything was working from past 1 month even after the firebase update , till few hours ago it only stopped working this morning

Comment: Did you recently add the facebook plugin? Please add your login code and pubspec.yaml

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal No I didnt. Login Code as in google sign in code? I dont think that would be a problem cuz same copy pasted code is working on a different practice app

Comment: @Sid and your pubspec? Maybe one of the modules there is causing the problem

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal I dint add or change anything there. I can provide you with the practice app code if you want which is identical in terms of working to the main app

Comment: @Sid No need for that if the that file is same. If you are saying that you added nothing new, lemme check the error log again. Add the code that Kiran gave and show the output as it may give us extra information on what went wrong

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal sign_in_failed This is the error that gets printed. Plus I just noticed that in practice app the user does gets in but the user is null smh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220661/discussion-between-siddharth-agrawal-and-sid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 3 lines

```
V/ViewRootImpl( 1327): The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
D/DecorView( 1327): onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@d773c2a[SignInHubActivity]
D/DecorView( 1327): onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@e79156a[MainActivity]
E/flutter ( 1327): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
```

Indicate that there is an error with your SHA1 key. I think due to the new windows update the key got changed in your computer. Just generate a new one and replace it

Answer (score 2):

The Platform Exception is because firebase is not being able to authenticate. Try catching the error and see the error code.

```
try {
[Firebase Login]
}
on PlatformException catch(error) {
print(error.code)
}
```

Comment: Hi kiran , I tried the same code in different app but it seems to work fine with those same exceptions

Comment: Thanks for your time Kiran it was my sha keys they got changed somehow